# Compare a string to the system time

Tags: sql, db2

Is it possible to have a query in DB2 that compares a value in a text field to the current system date?

```
select *   
  from table  
 where DOB < [current system time]
```

Comment: first look into the "text field" stored date format..
then accordingly you can build your query..
 ["Fun with date"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html) this link will help to work with system date..

Comment: What format is your 'text' date in?  Also, storing date/time/timestamp values in a character (or numeric) format is a terrible idea - at minimum, you've lost datatype safety, and depending on format, the ability to reliably sort your data.

Comment: I just want to be able to create an SQL statement that compares rows and the current time I'm running. It's kind of a lazy reason, but I'm working on a project where data updates everyday. And instead of changing my query to be the current day every day, I was hoping there would be a way to compare a value like 2012-01-01 to the system day.

Comment: So `[current system time]` is an input parameter?  I missed that earlier - is there a specific reason you're not using one of the standard 'special registers?  Say, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, which returns a nice timestamp type with 'now' in it?

Comment: I think the main thing that I didn't depict well was that I was comparing a date field, instead of a time stamp. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I'm guessing that your column has data formatted like this:

'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS'

If you are using DB2 9.7 and higher, you can use to_date, which is a lot like Oracle's to_date

```
 select 
 *
from
 table where 
 date(to_date(time_stamp,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')) < [current system time]
```

i haven't tested the above query.

Comment: There's no way to reliably know the format of the stored column until the OP tells us.  The particular format you've chosen to show (while not as bad as some) makes intelligent sorting of the data difficult, so it's to be hoped that something with the date values in reverse (ie ISO) order was used - `YYYY-MM-DD`.  If that's the case, better performance may be achieved by converting the current system time to a _text_ value (which would allow the use of an index on the column), instead of converting all rows to a date value (which cannot).

Answer (score 1):

my answer ended up being
`WHERE BIRTH_DATE BETWEEN '1800-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE`

The reserved word I was looking for was CURRENT_DATE.